# MySQL and PHP Unexpected T_Variable

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have a register.php script written and I get an unexpected T Variable when the command tries to execute. 
The error lies on line 15 at

```
('$_Post[username]','$_Post[sha_pass_hash]','$_Post[email]','2')";
```

I also have a second error in my syntax according to Dreamweaver at line 20 for

```
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## STOP

Inserting into a database directly from post is always a bad idea. This is the reason PHP is currently stuck with the very un-intuitive magic quotes.

You should at the very least be using mysql_real_escape_string() to escape your data. For example:

```
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
OR die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sha_pass_hash"]) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]) . "',
    '2'
)";

mysql_query($query);
```

The reason you have to do this is security based. For example if some malicious set the username field to `'); DROP TABLE users;` without first escaping your data. You would end up blindly running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (''); DROP TABLE users;
```

Which of course isn't going to end well for your application.

This is the **minimum** you should be doing.

In reality you should really be moving onto [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Which is a much more modern MySQL interface. 
Here is an example

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password', 'mysql_database');

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (
    '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) . "',
    '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["sha_pass_hash"]) . "',
    '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]) . "',
    '2'
)";

$mysqli->query($query);
```

You can even use MySQL in a procedural style. So if Object orientated programing isn't with in your reach yet you will have no problems with MySQLi.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, so right now I'm going off of your mysql_real_escape_string; currently I am still getting an error with yours as well as call to undefined function mysql_connect, but I am trying to sort through it; I'm told that it's from my php extensions not loading so as soon as I can get all that figured out then I'll be good to go and able to fix it to where it should work correctly. I've modded my php.ini and so now I think there's an underlying cause in my apache configuration. Sooner or later I'll have the solution and post it up for everyone. Thanks a lot for the tip; SQL Injection. new to me.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I checked the syntax inside of CMD prompt and running apache -t it tells me

Comment: Yes it sounds like you either don't have the MySQL module installed (windows) or didn't compile PHP with MySQL (linux). As i remember The old MySQL module isn't bundled with PHP anymore. You should probably save yourself the hassle and just use the MySQLi module.

Answer (score 2):

```
($_Post["username"],$_Post["sha_pass_hash"],$_Post["email"],'2')";
```

Remove the quotes..

Answer (score 1):

```
($_Post["username"],$_Post["sha_pass_hash"],$_Post["email"],'2')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
($_POST["username"],$_POST["sha_pass_hash"],$_POST["email"],'2')";
```

Lose the single quotes around the variables :)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
('".$_Post[username]."','".$_Post[sha_pass_hash]."','".$_Post[email]."','2')
```